# как пользоваться Enum, преобразовывая param[i] (<-тут int) в string (слово, которое соответствует данному param)?

Tags: c#, unity3d, enum

Есть класс с перечислением:

```
public class ObjectManagerScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public enum param1 {blala, Hi, Hello, Hmm};
    public enum param2{again, Ask, Queastion};
}
```

И другой класс, где я хочу выводить слова вместо цифр:

```
     public class ObjectChooser : MonoBehaviour {
    // тут пропущен код, который присваивает param1 и param2 числа
    // в итоге каждому param1 и param2 соответствует одно из чисел своего enum
        for (int i = 0; i < maxObjects; i++){
        Debug.Log(param1[i]);// это неправильно, просто я даже не знаю, как примерно это может выглядеть
                             // т.е тут имею ввиду, что, например, param1 = 2 (значит, Hello), и это i-элемент из maxObjects
        }
```

Вот как-то так. Попробовал поискать, но даже не знаю, как сформулировать вопрос

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это можно реализовать используя класс [Enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.enum(v=vs.110).aspx).

Количество констант в **enum** можно найти так:

```
 Enum.GetNames(typeof(param1)).Length;
или
  Enum.GetValues(typeof(param1)).Length;
```

Получить имя крнстанты так:

```
Enum.GetName(typeof(param1),индекс_константы)
```

---

В твоем случае:

```
for (int i = 0; i < maxObjects; i++)
    Debug.Log(Enum.GetName(typeof(param1),i);
```

Или так:

```
foreach(string s in Enum.GetNames(typeof(param1)))
    Debug.Log(s);
```

---

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.enum.getnames(v=vs.110).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.enum.getname(v=vs.110).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.enum.getvalues(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.enum.getvalues(v=vs.110).aspx

```
using System;

enum SignMagnitude { Negative = -1, Zero = 0, Positive = 1 };

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      foreach (var value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(SignMagnitude))) {
         Console.WriteLine("{0,3}     0x{0:X8}     {1}",
                           (int) value, ((SignMagnitude) value));
}   }
}
// The example displays the following output:
//         0     0x00000000     Zero
//         1     0x00000001     Positive
//        -1     0xFFFFFFFF     Negative
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/essfb559(v=vs.110).aspx

```
public class ParseTest
{
    [FlagsAttribute]
    enum Colors { Red = 1, Green = 2, Blue = 4, Yellow = 8 };

    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The entries of the Colors enumeration are:");
        foreach (string colorName in Enum.GetNames(typeof(Colors)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1:D}", colorName, 
                                         Enum.Parse(typeof(Colors), colorName));
        }
        Console.WriteLine();

        Colors orange = (Colors) Enum.Parse(typeof(Colors), "Red, Yellow");
        Console.WriteLine("The orange value {0:D} has the combined entries of {0}", 
                           orange);
    }
}
```